# Why would one specific SQL Server Database fail to convert VARCHAR to NUMERIC?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, sql-execution-plan

Is it possible that 2 different SQL Server databases, having the same schema and data, could process a query in a different way, and one of them throwing a " `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` " error, while the other one doesn't?

For example, see this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM DEPARTMENTS dpt
inner join
EMPLOYEES emp
on dpt.subgroup_id = emp.subgroup_id
WHERE
emp.employee_id = 12856
and
dpt.department_id in
(   
    select cm.mapped_value from CONFIGURATIONS c
    inner join
    CONFIG_MAPPINGS cm on cm.configuration_id = c.id
    where
    c.name = 'Department that can override self-destruction protocol'
)
```

The inner select subquery is returning either a value that can be cast to a number, or no results at all. So what I've noticed is that:

1. One database running `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60` executes the query without errors, as long as the inner statement will not return a non-numeric value
2. Another database running `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6` is always throwing the "`Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`" error, regardless of what the inner select query returns.

I've also noticed that if I change the subquery with another one that returns exactly the same, but without the inner join, the 2nd database is not throwing the error

```
SELECT count(*) FROM DEPARTMENTS dpt
inner join
EMPLOYEES emp
on dpt.subgroup_id = emp.subgroup_id
WHERE
emp.employee_id = 12856
and
dpt.department_id in
(   
    select cm.mapped_value FROM CONFIG_MAPPINGS
    WHERE cm.configuration_id = 'DPT_OVERRIDE_SDP'
)
```

I know that I should improve the query anyway, adding a `ISNUMERIC` check, but just out of curiosity, my question is:

Could it be that one these databases is processing the query in a different way (perhaps different execution plan) and always exposes the error, while the other database manages to execute the query?

Comment: "perhaps different execution plan" this is most likely it. The statistics on each instance are probably different, making the engine take different actions for the same query. One action might be doing the cast earlier.

Comment: You can safe-guard this by explicitly casting or making sure to evaluate columns that match on type.

Comment: Details matter:  Please read & act on [ask] & [mcve]. PS There are bugs in optimizers. Eg as a start google 'bug SQL Server Database fail to convert VARCHAR to NUMERIC' at site:[so] & site:[dba.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing the execution plans on both databases, I've noticed they are quite different.

If the plan was joining `DEPARTMENTS` and `CONFIG_MAPPINGS` before joining `CONFIG_MAPPINGS` with `CONFIGURATIONS`, and before the `c.name = ..` filter was applied, then we would be joining on `dpt.department_id (numeric) = cm.mapped_value`, while `mapped_value` would also contain non-numeric values at that point.

This is the case with the 2nd database, and this explains the conversion error

Answer (score 0):

Execute this queries:

```
select cm.mapped_value FROM CONFIG_MAPPINGS
WHERE cm.configuration_id = 'DPT_OVERRIDE_SDP' AND ISNUMERIC(cm.mapped_value)<>1
```

and

```
select cm.mapped_value from CONFIGURATIONS c
inner join
CONFIG_MAPPINGS cm on cm.configuration_id = c.id
where
c.name = 'Department that can override self-destruction protocol'
AND ISNUMERIC(cm.mapped_value)<>1
```

to see which values are the reason of error. Then you can use "ISNUMERIC(cm.mapped_value)=1" in your internal query to ignore them.

Comment: They both return no results